# Android Bluetooth Low Energy sometimes locking up

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have an app complete and ready to ship that connects to a custom bluetooth peripheral we have had made.
However I have just found an issue with the app that I can't pin down.

I am running all my Bluetooth operations in a `Service` and sometimes when I want the bluetooth operations to end, I end up with 1 peripheral still connected but i've lost all pointers to it. And every now and then the whole bluetooth stack seems to lock up and requires the phone to be rebooted.

I think the issues are arising when trying to clean out any connected devices after I stop scanning.
I have this cleanup method

```
private void clearAllDevices() {
        Log.e(TAG, "Clear all devices");
        for (int i = 0; i < _connectedPeripherals.size(); i++) {
            Log.e(TAG, "int i:" + i + " _connectedPeripherals size:" + _connectedPeripherals.size());
            BluetoothGatt gatt = (BluetoothGatt) _connectedPeripherals.get(i);
            gatt.disconnect();
        }
}
```

However I think sometimes a peripheral is half way through connecting at the same time as disconnecting from everything that has a connection.

Is there a better way to clean out all connected devices or devices that are in the process of being connected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bluetoothGatt.disconnect()` is not enough alone. You should also call `bluetoothGatt.close()`.

> *Once your app has finished using a BLE device, it should call* `close()` *so the system can release resources appropriately.*

See: [API Guides > Bluetooth Low Energy](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#close)

You may check the result of `bluetoothGatt.disconnect()` via `BluetoothGattCallback.onConnectionStateChange` callback.

Comment: Thanks. I shall try that tomorrow when I get our prototype back. I've never seen close() used in any of the tutorials I've read. Shall I call close() in the onConnectionStateChange callback once disconnected?

Comment: I used to call `close()` after `onConnectionStateChange` reports successful disconnection.

Comment: This was spot on, everything seems a lot more stable now. Thanks